# Side by Side Divs while dealing with Internet Explorer compatibility mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am designing a website using the MVC-3 framework.  While IE compatibility mode is not being used, it appears correctly and looks like this:

[image: a]

The code for this I am using is this:

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="title">                                 /* NUMBER 1 */
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/A_picture.png")" />
        </div>
        <div id="menucontainer">                         /* NUMBER 2 */
            <ul id="menu">
                /* some menu items*/
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="main">                                          /* NUMBER 3 */
   @RenderBody()
</div>
```

One day, I had the need to force my code to believe it was running IE7 for other formatting consistency issues.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

But now, forcing this breaks my initial website layout.  While using the forcing of IE7, it looks like this:

[image: b]

Thank you for staying with me through the explanation.  Now my question - how can I manipulate my div sections that are now broken to appear as they did in my first picture, while still forcing the emulation of IE7?

Any thoughts, ideas, and suggestions are much appreciated.

Edit: CSS

Some pieces of CSS I believe could be helpful to solve this problem are as follows.  Sorry, I obviously should have included this initially.

```
header,
footer,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

header, #header {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

nav, 
#menucontainer {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

div#title {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Providing your CSS would help.

Comment: I debated doing so, but the parts that I thought might affect the code weren't changing anything when I changed it.  I'm not very good with this stuff ;s lol but I will edit the CSS back in.

Comment: Does the HTML pass validation?  And I would never rely on compatibility mode.  You must use the actual browser version to be completely sure.

Comment: It uses a mix of HTML and mvc3 helpers, so I would assume it likely would fail html validation for these reasons alone.  If I state like I am that I wish to emulate IE7, I believe this would mean that I am not relying on compatability mode any longer and am forcing it to look like IE7.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to use `vertical-align`, for ie you sholud set smth like this:

```
#id_top_elements {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

but if you can show your css it may be heplfull ;)

or try smth like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
   #id_top_elements {
       position: relative; 
       top: -50%
   }
</style>
<![endif]–>
```

but now you need to add some wrapper for top elements, and it must have `position: absolute;`

Comment: To clarify, you are suggesting that I wrap the numbers 1 and 2 of my pictured items into a new div, and set the style of that new div to what you have written for #id_top_elements?

Comment: yeap, this is what im suggesting :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion, I will have to study this and implement!

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect your suggested example.  It currently doesn't work, but is this along the lines of what you are suggesting?  Thanks again for your response!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the floats you could also use

```
     display: inline-block; /*which works for most browsers including newer versions of ie, the following two lines are the fix for older versions of ie.*/
     *display: inline;
     zoom: 1;
```

Do this on any object/element that needs to 'sit' next to another object/element

Comment: Thank you, Stack Overflow, for your existence and thank you, @bluebela84, for being born :-). This solved my problem of divs styled as `inline-block` stacking vertically in IE compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly enough, the solution is simply to add one line to the #menucontainer css like this:

```
nav, 
#menucontainer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: inline;
}
```

The line added is "display: inline", and I added it to the number 2 div in my diagram.

Thank you for everyone who weighed in on this topic!